# How to use the output of the shell command in expect script's send

Tags: shell, expect

I have a expect script written to perform a login operation. The login requires the 2fa code, this code can be obtained by executing the shell command `2fa my_login`. Now how do I execute the **2fa** command and pass it's output to the **send** of my script?

I need to do something like `send -- "$(2fa my_login)"`. The output of the $(2fa my_login) should be passed to the send.

My script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn /home/local/apps/forticlientsslvpn/64bit/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server vpn.vpn-domain.com:10443 --vpnuser user-id

expect "Password for VPN:"

send -- "pass\n"

expect "Enter the time-based OTP generated in your device."

send -- "$(2fa my_login)\n"

expect eof
```

Comment: Try ```send $(2fa my_login)``` or ```send "$(2fa my_login)"```

Comment: No, it's not working. The first one throws errow and the second one throws variable not found

Comment: Expect uses the [Tcl language](http://www.tcl.tk/) which has different syntax from shell. You must learn Tcl to use Expect. If you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Comment: If you have to use Tcl, see [exec](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) for how to run a command and get the output.

Comment: @SanthoshTpixler : _I have a expect script written to perform a login operation._ Since you want to extend your existing script, you should post it. From your description, we don't even know whether you use _Tcl/Expect_, or _sexpect_, or any other expect variety.

Comment: @user1934428 I have edited with my script.

Comment: Thanks @sexpect--Expect_for_Shells  I switched to sexpect and it was a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect)

```
#!/bin/bash

export SEXPECT_SOCKFILE=/tmp/sexpect-bc-iGciUZ.sock

sexpect spawn -close-on-exit /home/local/apps/forticlientsslvpn/64bit/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server vpn.vpn-domaincom:10443 --vpnuser user

sexpect expect  -glob "Password for VPN:"

sexpect send -enter -- "pass"

sexpect expect  -glob "Enter the time-based OTP generated in your device."

auth=$(2fa my_login)

sexpect send -enter -- $auth

sexpect wait
```